# Redirecting to different pages

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node and express js. I am trying to create a simple registration and login page. I am facing a challenge, that is, after displaying a success alert message, I am not able to redirect back to welcome page. It is throwing me an error.

Here is my code:

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let redirect = require("express-redirect");
redirect(app);
let urlobj = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
let formidable = require("formidable");
let mongoclient = require("mongodb").MongoClient
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get("/welcome",function(req,res){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write("<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css'></head>");
res.write("<body class='homepage'>");
res.write("<form method='post' action='signup'>");
res.write("<button class='signup'>SIGN UP</button></form>");
res.write("<form method='post' action='login'>");
res.write("<button class='login'>LOGIN</button></form>");
res.write("</body></html>");
});
app.post("/signup",function(req,res){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write("<html><head> <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css'></head>");
res.write("<body class='homepage'>");
res.write("<form method='post' action='register'>");
res.write("<label style='top:80px'>Enter Your Name</label>")
res.write("<input style='top:100px' type='text' required placeholder='Enter Name' name='name'><br> 
<br>");
res.write("<label style='top:150px'>Enter Your Email</label>")
res.write("<input style='top:170px' type='email' required placeholder='Enter Email' name='email'><br> 
<br>");
res.write("<label style='top:220px'>Enter Your Contact</label>")
res.write("<input style='top:240px' type='number' pattern='[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}' required 
placeholder='Enter Contact' name='contact'><br><br>");
res.write("<label style='top:290px'>Enter Your Address</label>")
res.write("<input style='top:310px' type='text' required placeholder='Enter Address' name='addr'><br> 
<br>");
res.write("<button class='register' style='top:360px' href='/welcome'>REGISTER</button>");
res.write("</form></body></html>");
});
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
mongoclient.connect(urlobj,{ useUnifiedTopology: true },function(err,db){
    if(err)
    res.write(err);
    else
    {
        let dataobj = db.db("mydatabase");
        let form=formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(
            req, function(err, fields, files){
      let  docobj={
            name:fields.name,
            email:fields.email,
            contact:fields.contact,
            address:fields.addr
        };
dataobj.collection("Student").insertOne(docobj,function(err,data){
    if(err)
    res.write("Something went Wrong:  "+err);
    else
    {
res.send("<script>alert('Resgistered Successfully! Please Login')</script>");
return res.redirect("/welcome");
    db.close();
    }
});
});
}
});
});
app.listen(3030);
```

Here is the error:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.location (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:888:15)
at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:926:18)
at C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\project\trialproject.js:57:13
at executeCallback (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:70:5)
at C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert_one.js:34:21
at handleCallback (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:102:55)
at C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\common_functions.js:262:5
at handler (C:\Users\Ibrahim Bharmal\desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:943:24) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Please can someone guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

as mention in  your error that you Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

in your code

```
  else
   {
    res.send("  
    <script>alert('Resgistered Successfully! Please Login')</script>  
   ");    // you send response to client
    
    
    return res.redirect("/welcome");   // and than you again send response to client that's why error occur
        db.close();
        }
```

so you have to handle alert at client side
so you have to do it this

```
          else
            {
 const query = true;
      
 res.redirect('/welcome' + query);

    }
```

welcome.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script> // include it in header 
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('<%: TempData["Resultat"]%>');
  });
```

in nodejs router file

```
app.get('/welcome', function(req, res) {
      var passedVariable = req.query.valid;
          (passedVaribale == true)
           ? console.log('this is true') : console.log('do something');

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the return keyword before you redirect